# Using Directive for Focusing Input Field

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using a directive for focusing an input field. This works great, when entering first time the page. But this method is not called when I navigate back, or pop to a specific page. I guess it's because `ngAfterViewInit()` is not called anymore. I tried to use `ionViewDidEnter()` / `onPageDidEnter()` but in this case, the focus get not called at all.

Using in some page:

```
 <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="matrikel" focus>
```

**focuser.ts**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[focus]' // Attribute selector
})

export class FocusDirective {

    @Input() focus: any;


    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer, private globalVariables: GlobalsVariable) { }

   ngAfterViewInit(){

            const searchInput = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(searchInput, 'focus', []);
            }, 650);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ionViewCanEnter()`. Which will call before the `ionViewDidLoad()`.

**html**

```
<ion-input #focusInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="matrikel">
```

**focuser.ts**

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

    export class FocusDirective {
    @ViewChild('focusInput') focus: any;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer, private globalVariables: GlobalsVariable) { }

    ionViewCanEnter() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.focus.setFocus();
        }, 500);
   }
   }
```